# how can I solve Error starting Web connector Jboss?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jboss, migration

I try to migrate my application from Tomcat Server to JBoss6.3.0.

My schedule.war file works ok in Tomcat, but when i move it in
C:...\EAP-6.3.0\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\deployments
the server displayed thet error:

```
09:04:25,907 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBA
S015877: Stopped deployment schedule.war (runtime-name: schedule.war) in 284ms
09:04:25,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBA
S014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit
."schedule.war".POST_MODULE
      service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in
service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a port conflict. JBoss is trying to use the same port that TomCat already uses.

Change the http port in the file standalone.xml (or other profile you are using) on standalone\configuration like:

```
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8179"/>
```

and restart the server.